# How to re-render Wordpress Guttenberg block?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'am doing custom WP plugin that work with Guttenberg editor.
One of functionality is that user select part of text in editor. Click on button. JS take selected text, process it and replace selected code with custom shortcode line. 
E.g. we have text

> Lorem ipsum Custom Word and other words

User select "Custom Word" click on button and js dynamicaly replace it like

> Lorem ipsum [custom_shortcode title="Custom Word"] and other words

I set block content with edited content with jQuery like this:

```
var all_content =    tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
all_content = all_content.replace( string_to_replace, shortcode_string );
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent( all_content )
```

I think that not right way to apply content to block.

SO that all works fine. Problem become when I click on Save or on Preview

Final result doesnt store my inserted shortcode code. As I understand as basicaly block content was not rendered by Guttenberg and I just make visual insertion in html.

Iam new in Guttenberg and not sure how I can make it to re-render edited block so changes are applied.

Iv tried after doing all replacements resave Guttenberg content with

```
var editedContent = wp.data.select( "core/editor" ).getEditedPostContent().content;
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost( { content: editedContent } );
```

But with no luck. Can anyone help me ? TNX

Comment: You might not want to change the whole content of a post but only of a single block first. It sounds like you want to add that functionality to paragraphs? `wp.data` has functions for getting the selected block. you could check if its a paragraph and then change its content.